# Append to table with node js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When using console.table() you have to provide all the data at the beginning, `console.table([{Type: message.channel.type, Username: message.author.tag, Message: message.content}])`, but is there any way I can add on to it? Right now, its making a new table for every discord message:

```
┌─────────┬──────┬──────────────┬─────────┐
│ (index) │ Type │   Username   │ Message │
├─────────┼──────┼──────────────┼─────────┤
│    0    │ 'DM' │ 'Cacti#7636' │ '*ping' │
└─────────┴──────┴──────────────┴─────────┘
```

And it repeats this for every message, but is there a way I can just append a row to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/table there is nothing similar to that, so i would maintain a list with the entries i want to print and print them all in one go. I'm guessing that's why it supports receiving a list on the first param, so i would initialize an array:

```
let arr = []
```

and then just add items to that array, like:

```
arr.push({ Type: message.channel.type, Username: message.author.tag, Message: message.content });
```

and then

```
console.table(arr);
```

A simple test:

```js
let arr = []

const obj = {Type: 'DM', Username:'Cacti#7636', Message: '*ping' }

arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj);

console.table(arr)
```

check the console to see the printing result

Comment: The problem with that is I want to see the messages arrive in real time, not every so often, but thanks anyway!